# SQL Server 2014 Express on Windows 10

Tags: sql-server, heidisql

I've downloaded and installed SQL Server 2014 Express on Windows 10, I've been through this loop at least 3 times now. The installation completes without warnings or errors. I have chosen to use Window authentication. I'm trying to use HeidiSQL to connect to SQL Server. I already have MariaDB installation and am able to connect to that using HeidiSQL.

When I connect to MariaDB I am able to select Databases from the drop down combo, but not for SQL Server. I don't seem to be able to connect with HeidiSQL.

In HeidiSQL, the settings are:

- Network type: Microsoft SQL Server (TCP/IP, experimental)
- Hostname / IP: 127.0.0.1
- Ticked checkbox 'Use Windows authentication'
- Port: 1433

I can't select a Database, if I click on the Open button after a while it comes up with:

> SQL Error(17): [DBNETLIB]ConnectionOpen (COnnect()).]SQL does not exist or access denied SQL Server does not exist or access denied.

Comment: [This might be helpful.](http://serverfault.com/q/82007/296909)

Comment: Thank you, I followed the instructions and added an ODBD Data Source via the "System DSN" tab.  I selected Integrated Windows authentication, then all the default settings, when clicked "Test Data Source...", the dialog showing "TESTS COMPLETED SUCCESSFULLY!", but I still can't connect via HeidiSQL.  The telnet instruction didn't work either.

Comment: Since the question is well-received there, maybe post your question there, linking to the other question and explain why it didn't help.

Comment: There aren't many things in common between questions, as far as I can tell the host O/S isn't Windows 10 and the version of MsSQL is 2005.

Comment: @SPlatten I got to a similar stage as you, worked from MS SQL Server Management Studio, but not from HeidiSQL. I had to do 2 thing to get it finally to work: On the server side disable the dynamic port feature and set a fixed port number. 2) In HeidiSQL, add the port number to the IP field: "10.0.01\SQLEXPRESS,1433" It seems it would not use this port by default although the dialog box would suggest otherwise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to use HeidiSQL's network type `Microsoft SQL Server (TCP/IP)`, you need to **activate TCP/IP protocol** in your MSSQL configuration.

Further on, I am unsure if `Windows authentication` worked for me, as I'm always using the default `SA` user, which is created while installing SQL Server.

Apart from that, you should be able to connect using `<yourmachine>\SQLEXPRESS` on port 1433.

Answer (score 1):

Use **Microsoft SQL Server (named pipe)** as *Network type* and **.\SQLEXPRESS** for *Hostname / IP*

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server **Express** by default installs as a named instance called `SQLEXPRESS` - so for your "hostname", try one of these:

- `.\SQLEXPRESS`
- `(local)\SQLEXPRESS`
- `yourmachine\SQLEXPRESS`
- `your-ip-address\SQLEXPRESS`

Those should work.

Comment: I tried each one of the suggestions, same result: SQL Error(6): [DBNETLIB][ConnectionOpen (Connect().]Specified SQL server not found Specified SQL server not found.

Comment: I've installed MS SQL Server Management Studio and can connect using that to the local instance of the database.  However I cannot add a new Database using it either, if I right click on Databases and select New Database, an error dialog is displayed "Cannot show requested dialog.  Additional information: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Sqm. Version=12.0.0.0. Culture=neutral....